# Como fazer o React retornar componentes específicos dependendo do state?

Tags: node.js, react

Gostaria saber como fazer o React retornar o componente dependo do `state` pai.

```
function One(){
   return <div>1</div>
}
function Two(){
   return <div>2</div>
}
function Main(){
   const {user} = useUser()//dados do login...
   console.log(user)

   //stats da pagina..
   const [main, setmain] = useState('home')
   return(
   <div className={"mainbody"}>
      <Headerman/>
      <Navbarmain setmain={setmain} />
      if(main ==='home'){
         return(<One></One>)
      } 
      else{return(<Two></Two>)}
   </div>
   );
}
```

Queria retornar um componente se o `state` estiver com valor definido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer usar a [renderização condicional](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html), não insira blocos `if` dentro do código que renderiza o componente. Primeiro que do jeito que você fez está incorreto e segundo porque não bom inserir lógicas muito complexas em código cujo propósito é somente renderizar, não fica muito fácil de entender e organizar o código.

Neste seu caso, você quer renderizar um componente ou outro dependendo do `main`, neste caso o que você poderia fazer é criar uma funcão que verifica o estado e retorna determinando componente, depois você chama esta funcão dentro do código renderizador usando chaves `{}`.

Seria algo como esta funcão que chamei de `render`, ela possui a lógica do `if/else`:

```
 const render = () => {
    if(main ==='home'){
       return <One />
    } 
    else{
      return <Two />
    }
  }
```

Depois, basta chamar ela dentro do código renderizador:

```
 return (
   <div className={"mainbody"}>
      <Headerman/>
      <Navbarmain setmain={setmain} />
      { render() } // <= chame ela aqui
    </div>
  );
```

Veja como o código que renderiza ficou mais simples de se entender sem `if/else`. Agora veja um exemplo abaixo executável que tem um botão `Mudar o "main"` que altera o estado do `main` e renderiza um componente `<One />` ou `<Two />` de acordo com o valor de `main`:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function One(){
   return <div>1</div>
}
function Two(){
   return <div>2</div>
}

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const [main, setMain] = useState('home');
  
  const render = () => {
    if(main ==='home'){
       return <One />
    } 
    else{
      return <Two />
    }
  }
  
  const mudarMain = () => {
    if (main === "home") return setMain("")
    else return setMain("home")
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <button onClick={mudarMain}>
        Mudar o "main"
      </button>
      { render() }
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Teste condicional: " />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: OBRIGADO, pela ajuda amigo!!!